# PayPal Payment - PHP API

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment

I need to have in my website the possibility to make some payments through PayPal to registered users. I need to do this direct from my website, without login in to PayPal. Is this possible?

Comment: short answer is yes, but you'll need an SSL certificate, among other things...

Comment: First time? Get ready for a lot of documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I believe it's possible using their 'Website Payments Pro' and it might be possible using 'Express Checkout' but I can't remember. Have a look at their [developer pages](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/global/uk) for more information.